# EventToCommand not coming with LightMvvm in WPF4 in .net 4 framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mvvm-toolkit, simple-mvvm

I am not getting EventToCommand. My assembly is as followes

```
<Window x:Class="EfesBetGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vmMainWindow="clr-namespace:EfesBetGUI.ViewModel"
        xmlns:DateTimeUC="clr-namespace:EfesBetGUI.View.UserControls"        
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4"
        xmlns:mvvmgalasoftCommand="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4"
        xmlns:LightCmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        xmlns:util="clr-namespace:EfesBetGUI.Util"
        Title="MainWindow" >
```

but inspite of that also I am not getting EventToCommand .I would like to mention Iam using framework 4.0 and visual studio 12. Any help is welcome.Thanking you,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx), the `EventToCommand` class sits in the `Extras` dll, so I would try the following xmlns:

```
xmlns:mvvmgalasoftCommand="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

Note that I've added the `Extras` in the assembly name. not sure if you need the `WPF4` suffix, you can try it with/without it and see if it works

Comment: thanks for response. As you can see I have added one image of my reference. in my xaml you can see I have already used xmlns:LightCmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight" as suggested by you.

Comment: I tried every way but it is not working.I applied your code also.I have a humble request may I send you my code in anyway

Answer (score 1):

How about using directly:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
```